# Tiggers , before inserted trigger?

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have two tables , table (files) and table (Hashes) i want to create a procedure that inserts new (file) wich will add a ( Hash ) if not exists and then inserts its ( ID ) in the ( files) table , if exists select the (ID) and insert it , and i also must use ( before insert on files trigger ) i ried but it either gives me an CONSTRAINT error OR Insert in hash and no file inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE `Hashes` (
  `ID` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Counter` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Hash` (`Hash`)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `Files` (
  `ID` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ParentPath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Size` double NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `ParentID` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `HashID` int(255) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_Hash_ID` (`HashID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Hash_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`HashID`) REFERENCES `hashes` (`ID`)
)

////////
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Files_Insert
(                      
parmName VARCHAR(255),                 
parmParentPath VARCHAR(255),         
parmSize DOUBLE,   
parmDate DATE,
parmParentID INTEGER,
parmHash VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Files( Name, ParentPath, Size, Date, ParentID, HashID) 
    VALUES(parmName, parmParentPath, parmSize, parmDate, parmParentID,    LAST_INSERT_ID());

END;

////////////
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Insert_File BEFORE INSERT ON Files 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Hash( Hash, Counter) 
    VALUE( parmHash, 1) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), Counter = Counter + 1;

END;
```

Comment: let us know your full error message

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cloudimagesdb`.`files`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Hash_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`HashID`) REFERENCES `hashes` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: your error message clearly showing that it has foreign key relation .for that   you have to create fk relation  first or disable foreign key  : to disable foreign key SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;  and to enable foreign key  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: The foreign key is created , and i dont want to disable it !!!

Comment: if you dont want foreign key disable then in your trigger before insert  into hash table .. insert your foreign key that reference table in that trigger

Comment: well thats what ( trigger before insert on files ) supposed to do , if hash exisits increment counter and get id send it to procedure else insert hash  and get the id and send it to procedure !! ( Files table contains foreign key hashID )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use delimiter in your trigger like below that will work for you

```
delimiter \\
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Insert_File BEFORE INSERT ON Files 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Hash( Hash, Counter) 
    VALUE( parmHash, 1) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(ID), Counter = Counter + 1;

END\\ 
delimiter ;
```

Comment: that doesnt work the Problem have nothing to do with the Delimiter , and i checked it thank you

Comment: have you created unique key ??let me know your error message

Comment: param hash in the trigger not defiend and i replaced it with NEW.Hash but gaves me ( hash not found in new) !!

Comment: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`cloudimagesdb`.`files`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Hash_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`HashID`) REFERENCES `hashes` (`ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)